# How to give a proper error message

Tags: c#

According to my code "Your Password Has Been Changed successfully!, Congratulations!" message is popping up even though the update is not worked. how can I give an error message if the update is not taken place(It seems there is an error in my update statement too..). Actually I couldn't imagine how to use the if statement here..

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=e-learningsystem; uid=root; password=123;port=3307;");
        connection.Open();
         try
         {

             MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE student Set Password= '" + TextBox3.Text + "' WHERE UserName='" + TextBox1.Text + "' AND Password='"+TextBox2.Text+"'", connection);
             cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
             Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Your Password Has Been Changed successfully!, Congratulations!')</script>");
             connection.Close();
            }
         catch (Exception ex)
           {
             Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert(ex.Message)</script>");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Passwords shouldn't be stored in plain text

Comment: Also, this code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

`cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of rows affected. So if your query updates any record then it will return more than 0 rows (in this case 1 row of that particular user)
So try this

```
if(cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()>0)
{
   // successfull 
}
else
{ 
  // failure
}
```

and Please do not pass values like this in your query. Try using **SqlParameter** to pass the parameters in query to avoid *Sql Injection*.

Comment: I think my update statement also not working am I have any error????

Comment: does your `textbox2` contains old password?

Comment: ya it s having the old password

Answer (score 0):

[Sachin's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007043/how-to-give-a-proper-error-message/17007055#17007055) give you the solution for your message box popup issue.

But Why you implement your own authentication mechanism? is there any reason not to use [asp.net membership providers?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx)

Assume you have good reason to that. But if you are implementing custom authentication check this [Sample Membership Provider Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

For example ChangePassword method :

```
public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPwd, string newPwd)
{
    // validate the user first, you are not doing any validation 
    // logged in user can change any other users password in your approach 
    if (!ValidateUser(username, oldPwd))
    return false;

    //new password validation and giving proper message if failed 
    // skip this code from given link

    // use parameterized query as below 
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE Users "  +
          " SET Password = ?, LastPasswordChangedDate = ? " +
          " WHERE Username = ? AND ApplicationName = ?", conn);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = EncodePassword(newPwd);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastPasswordChangedDate", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = username;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = pApplicationName;


    int rowsAffected = 0;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
            // this is how you can check whether row updated or not 
        rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (OdbcException e)
    {
        // you need to have proper error handling as well 
        if (WriteExceptionsToEventLog)
        {
          WriteToEventLog(e, "ChangePassword");

          throw new ProviderException(exceptionMessage);
        }
        else
        {
          throw e;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    if (rowsAffected > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```